# Remove name in PWA splash screen

Tags: android, splash-screen, progressive-web-apps, manifest.json

how can I remove the name in the splash screen of my progressive web app?

The app name is already in the logo / icon. That's why I don't want to see the name in the bottom of the splash screen again.

example manifest.json:

```
{
  "name": "HackerWeb",
  "short_name": "HackerWeb",
  "start_url": ".",
  "display": "standalone",
  "background_color": "#fff",
  "description": "A simply readable Hacker News app.",
  "icons": [{
    "src": "images/touch/homescreen48.png",
    "sizes": "48x48",
    "type": "image/png"
  }, {
    "src": "images/touch/homescreen72.png",
    "sizes": "72x72",
    "type": "image/png"
  }]
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is not a way to selectively display the app name on the splash screen. The recommended approach is to develop a logo that will work being displayed next to your application neame. Potentially you could try setting an empty string for the name but that could have unintended consequences including making browsers start ignoring the manifest altogether.