# Hide Android PWA title in splash screen

Tags: android, progressive-web-apps

I'm currently setting up my web app for progressive web app support but I can't seem to stop the name / short_name property from displaying in the Android splash screen.

Is there anyway to hide the text and only show the icon ?

Comment: @Riley Davidson Did the below answer your question?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove name in PWA splash screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46647984/remove-name-in-pwa-splash-screen)

Answer (score 1):

[You have to specify at least one of two](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-app-manifest/#splash-screen) - name or short name., Tricking with space chars is not an option as "Name" will be used in install prompt which is important for convincing the user to add to home screen. This is a space which is seeing some changes(like how Chrome treats name and short name changed in recent past). You can hope to see hiding options. But no luck for now.

Comment: @RileyDavidson why that script? if you have any question on the above answer, give proper clarity or if it solves your question, mark accepted.